# distutils Extension arguments -- include vs depends vs source?

Tags: python, include, distutils

I'm trying to understand the dependency structure of pandas' cython [extensions](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/setup.py#L471) in setup.py.

`distutils.extension.Extension` has arguments `sources`, `depends`, and `include_dirs`, and I can't figure out the difference between these.  In particular, there are a bunch of places in the pandas case where I can delete entries in `depends` (or `pxdfiles`) without breaking the build.

What is the distinction between these three arguments?

**Update following answer from @phd**:
I appreciate the thought, will try to better communicate the source of my confusion.

In the pandas setup.py file linked above, the `pandas._libs.tslib` extension is passed to `distutils.extension.Extension` with the args/kwargs:

```
ext = Extension('pandas._libs.tslib',
    sources=['pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx',
             'pandas/_libs/src/util.pxd',
             'pandas/_libs/src/datetime/np_datetime.c',
             'pandas/_libs/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.c',
             'pandas/_libs/src/period_helper.c'],
    depends=['pandas/_libs/src/datetime/np_datetime.h',
             'pandas/_libs/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.h',
             'pandas/_libs/src/period_helper.h',
             'pandas/_libs/src/datetime.pxd'],
    include_dirs=['pandas/_libs/src/klib', 'pandas/_libs/src'])
```

Take e.g. `util.pxd` in the `sources` entry.  Is this not redundant with the presence of `pandas/_libs/src` in the `include_dirs` entry?  `tslib` imports directly from `datetime.pxd` which has "imports" of the form `cdef extern from "datetime/np_datetime.h"` and `cdef extern from "datetime/np_datetime_strings.h"`.  Are those "allowed" because of the presence of the "*.c" files in the `sources` or the "*.h" files in the `depends` or both or...

I've tried a whole bunch of permutations of removing subsets of these dependencies, have not seen many patterns in terms of which break the build.

Answer (score 0):

See the [detailed docs](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Extension) and [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py) for `build_ext` command.

`sources` is a list of source files (`*.c`) to compile the extension.

`depends` — a list of additional files the extensions is required to compile.

`include_dirs` — a list of directories where a compiler will look for include (header) files (`*.h`).

`pxdfiles` are [Cython-specific](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/pxd_files.html).

Comment: I have added a header file in `depends` but `python3 -m build` ignores it. The header file is not included in the `tar.gz` file. As a consequence, `pip install` fails to compile since the header file is missing. The documentation is confusing.

Comment: `build` is about compiling extensions. `tar.gz` is a source distribution, the result of command `sdist`; it's a completely different command and requires different configuration is `setup.py`.

Comment: thank you. Indeed `sdist` requires a `MANIFEST.in` file since it won’t include header files by default. I just found this out. After adding this file, the `tar.gz` contains all required files and I managed to get my package built with `pip install`.